# How to sync CI configs for Gitlab, Github, Travis, Circle, etc.?

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, github-actions

Is there an abstraction for defining continuous integration pipelines which can then produce individual config files for particular CI providers? This would be handy especially for projects intended to serve as boilerplate.

Currently I am finding myself needing to manually write and sync both a .gitlab-ci.yml and a .github/workflows/ci.yml.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question, unless you can abstract **all** your CI scripts into shell scripts, then from what I can see there would lots of periodical porting process between the different CI providers.

Also, different CI providers has its own ideology of the perfect build pipeline as well as predefined setup.

With that being said, I would love to see some utility tools help me migrate the scripts and converge my CI setup into Github Action world.